# How to create a single yaml release pipeline for multiple build artifacts

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-yaml-pipelines

We have seperate build definitions for each module which generates artifacts. Could someone help me how to create a common yaml release pipeline for all the build definitions

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There's not a lot of detail to the request, but in very general terms, if I were building a multi-artifact release, I would take this approach:

1. Choose (or create) a repo that you will use for release pipelines (I have a repo for common Azure DevOps pipelines work, I might create a folder under than, or you could create your own repo).
2. Within the repo you've chosen, create a YAML file to hold your release definition.
3. Declare pipeline artifacts as resources to the new pipeline using the following syntax (from learn.microsoft.com) - use one `- pipeline` reference for each build artifact contributing to the release:

```
resources:        # types: pipelines | builds | repositories | containers | packages
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: string  # identifier for the resource used in pipeline resource variables
    project: string # project for the source; optional for current project
    source: string  # name of the pipeline that produces an artifact
    version: string  # the pipeline run number to pick the artifact, defaults to latest pipeline successful across all stages; Used only for manual or scheduled triggers
    branch: string  # branch to pick the artifact, optional; defaults to all branches; Used only for manual or scheduled triggers
    tags: [ string ] # list of tags required on the pipeline to pickup default artifacts, optional; Used only for manual or scheduled triggers
    trigger:     # triggers aren't enabled by default unless you add trigger section to the resource
      branches:  # branch conditions to filter the events, optional; Defaults to all branches.
        include: [ string ]  # branches to consider the trigger events, optional; Defaults to all branches.
        exclude: [ string ]  # branches to discard the trigger events, optional; Defaults to none.
      tags: [ string ]  # list of tags to evaluate for trigger event, optional
      stages: [ string ] # list of stages to evaluate for trigger event, optional
```

4. Build out the rest of your deployment pipeline
5. In the Azure Pipelines portal, create a new pipeline, and choose your pipeline YAML file from the repo in which you placed it.

Comment: This doesn't wait for all the pipeline resources. Instead it will trigger a separate run when each pipeline resource completes.